# Estimated number (Heuristics) of operations between Two Integers

Tags: integer, dijkstra, a-star, heuristics, integer-arithmetic

I have two integers `A` and `B` and I want to get, WLOG say, from `A` to `B` with minimum numbers of the following operations:

- Add or subtract 1
- Multiple or divide by 2
- Square the number

Currently I am solving this problem using A* search where operation weights are all 1's with heuristics of 0 (Basically Dijkstra's Algorithm, I guess). But I want a better heuristics to explore less.
So far, all my attempts have failed. For example, if both are positive and unequal, I tried to estimate by squaring and doubling as much as possible. I also tried to think in terms of bit strings but 111 + 1 = 1000 makes me feel like it will not be a good heuristics. I want some ideas, if not solutions, to come up with a good heuristics.

Answer (score 0):

If `A > B * 2^n`, you know it must take at least n steps since you can only divide by 2. Solving for `n` we get `ceil(log_2(A/B))` as a heuristic. This assumes A and B have the same sign.

If `A < B` then we're allowed to square, so unfortunately the equation to solve is `A^(2^n) < B`, or `ceil(log_2(log_A(B)))` as a lower-bound.  This assumes A ≥ 2.

Comment: Kinda get the ideas of constructing these equations...I guess I will have to find more for other conditions. One quirk about my searching algorithm is that sometimes the algorithm tries to take advantage of integer overflow. For example, if `A` is 2^16 then for 32-bit integer, squaring will make it 0 which if `B`, then there is only one step. Oh well, it is what it is in programming after all.

Comment: And I am getting `floor` instead of `ceil`. For example, for the first one, we have `log_2(A/B) > n` and this should lead to floor instead of ceil?